# Модификаторы доступа в C#

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Допустим, я задал классу модификатор доступа internal, а переменной в этом классе public. Вопрос, эта переменная будет иметь модификатор доступа internal(как модификатор доступа класса) или public(как модификатор доступа переменной)?

Comment: А что вам мешает проверить это самостоятельно?

Comment: Ну в общем случае вроде действует самый строгий из модификаторов.

Comment: Ну а как вы например из другого класса получите доступ к `public` свойству объекта с модификатором `private`, если вы не сможете получить доступ к самому объекту? Ваш вопрос как минимум странный.

Comment: что имеется ввиду по _public переменная в классе_?

Comment: Подозрительно похоже на вопрос из учебника...

Answer (score 4):

К `public` переменной можно обратиться из **любого места сборки**, где объявлен `internal` класс.
*Разумеется, для этого ещё нужно получить экземпляр класса.*

### Пояснение

Модификатор `internal` у класса означает что нельзя будет использовать его **извне той сборки, в котрой он объявлен** (то есть нельзя в другой сборрке создать переменную с таким типом, вызвать конструктор этого класса, или унаследоваться от него, а так же обращаться к его статическим членам).
При этом внутри той сборки, в которой класс объявлен нельзя сделать `public` член у `public` класса, возвращающий экземпляр `internal` класса - об этом позаботится компилятор, и выкинет `CS0050`.
В конечном счёте, это означает что в других сборках никак нельзя получить экземпляр `internal` класса.

Модификтор `public` у члена класса означает что к нему может обратиться кто-угодно, но только через экземпляр класса.

В документации можно почитать: [internal (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal).

Comment: _Модификатор internal у класс означает что нельзя будет создать переменную с таким типом, или вызвать конструктор этого класса._ - эм, это почему эт?

Comment: Забыл добавить "в другой сборке", поправлю ответ.

Comment: @ion, если ответ решил вашу проблему - пожалуйста, не забывайте отметить его соответствующим образом.